# Spring Boot authentication not available from error page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

Depending on whether the user is logged in, I want to display an element on an error page e.g.

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
Logged in
</div>
```

The problem is, however is that the current Authentication Principal is being cleared for some reason. I thought it had something to do with the [No Auth for You](https://github.com/olle/no-auth-for-you) bug, so I added

```
security.filter-dispatcher-types: ASYNC, FORWARD, INCLUDE, REQUEST, ERROR
```

However still the problem persists. I loaded up both projects and debug-logged spring security. With the *No Auth For You* project I'm getting:

```
SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@76d66409
Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
/error at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
/error at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImp.....
```

Which gives the correct security context.

With my project I'm getting

```
SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
Cleared thread-bound request context: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@380b96d
Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
/error at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
/error at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
No HttpSession currently exists
No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
```

So the issue seems to be "No HttpSession currently exists". I am using Redis Sessions, if that makes a difference. However I don't know really where to go from here, when it comes to debugging.

I am using the GlobalDefaultException handler code from the [Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc), if that makes any difference. However I actually ported this handler to the *No Auth For You* project, so I don't believe it is that.

If I leave this error page and view any other page, then I am still logged in.

**Update**

I removed Redis and it could find the session. Maybe it is something to do with Tomcat and Redis?

**Update 2018**

I have looked at this again, and I think it has something to do with the GlobalExceptionHandler (as mentioned before taken from Spring's blog).

> "If you want to have a default handler for any exception, there is a slight wrinkle. You need to ensure annotated exceptions are handled by the framework."

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler
{
    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    @ResponseStatus(value = INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String exception(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        Exception e,
        Model model
    ) throws Exception
    {
       // other logging things here

       if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
       {
            // template that renders this can't access the SecurityContext
            throw e;
       }

       // this template can access the SecurityContext
       return "error";
    }
}
```

The caught exception is able to access the SecurityContext, however the re-thrown exceptions (handled by Spring) can't access the SecurityContext.

Remember that both templates can access the SecurityContext, when Redis is not being used. I looked at the [documentation for Spring Session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html) and it says

> "...[t]his creates a Spring Bean with the name of springSessionRepositoryFilter that implements Filter. The filter is what is in charge of replacing the HttpSession implementation to be backed by Spring Session."

So maybe this bean isn't being used for some reason?

Under Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 it works, so I wonder what was changed

```
 DEBUG 3767 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /errorTest/notFound at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:      'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
 DEBUG 3767 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.d.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils    : Opening RedisConnection
 DEBUG 3767 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] io.lettuce.core.RedisChannelHandler      : dispatching command AsyncCommand [type=HGETALL, output=MapOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command]
  [SNIP REDIS]
 DEBUG 3767 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.d.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils    : Closing Redis Connection
 DEBUG 3767 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT:    'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@936f4f11: Authentication:   org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

I think it is related to the following issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5737

> I think it makes sense to change SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration to use the ERROR dispatch type by default. The ERROR dispatch type is also the  default of Spring Security's Servlet Java Config.
>
> The reason the ERROR dispatch type makes sense for Spring Security is   many times navigation is based on the permissions of the current user. Without Spring Security being populated, the error page may not have
> meaningful navigation.

Comment: I suspect the problem might be in your security configuration. Can you share the class which is extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter if any?

Comment: As noted, switching from Redis to Spring in memory session store "fixed" the issue, so I think it is unlikely to be the security configuration.